# joda + how can we override epoch date with todays date

Tags: java, date, jodatime

I have a requirement, where I need to override the date

when I parse time(hh:mm:ss) using SimpleDateFormat, what i get is object of date (Thu Jan 01 hh:mm:ss IST 1970)
i want to overide epoch date with today date(without time).

is there a api or method in joda/jdk, which can do this for me

Comment: why are you not trying `SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'");
      date = sdf.parse(strDate);` for jodatime you can get some info here-http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/userguide.html#Working_with_DateTime

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you can't, but what you can do, is merge the values from the "time" conversion with another date (like today)...for example

```
try {
    Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss").parse("13:30:51");
    System.out.println(date);

    Calendar time = Calendar.getInstance();
    time.setTime(date);

    Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();
    today.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, time.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
    today.set(Calendar.MINUTE, time.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
    today.set(Calendar.SECOND, time.get(Calendar.SECOND));

    System.out.println(today.getTime());
} catch (ParseException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

There's probably a really fancy way of doing this with less code, but I was trying to avoid deprecated methods.

For me, this outputs...

```
Thu Jan 01 13:30:51 EST 1970
Thu Oct 31 13:30:51 EST 2013
```

Beware though, this does not reset the milliseconds value of the `today` `Calendar`, in case that's important...

Comment: Caution: By setting the attributes of a calendar instance directly one has to check for illegal dates. (Does the day exist in the given month? Does the hour exist on the given day (Daylight Saving Time issues)? etc.)